# Facing an error while running "truffle compile"

Tags: solidity, truffle, solc, truffle-compile, solcjs

I'm facing an error while running truffle compile-

```
Error: Failed to fetch the Solidity compiler from the following locations: https://relay.trufflesuite.com/solc/bin/,https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/,https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/. Are you connected to the internet?
```

Here is my `truffle-config.js` -

```
require("babel-register");
require("babel-polyfill");

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "HTTP://127.0.0.1:",
      port: "7545",
      networkd_id: "*", //match any network
    },
  },
  contracts_directory: "./src/contracts/",
  contracts_build_directory: "./src/truffle_abis",
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.5.0",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: It seems a network issue. Try again later, check with another internet provider, or the proxy configuration if it applies in your case.

Comment: @Ismael, it is actually not. It's quite a common error right now that is faced by windows users trying to use truffle.

Comment: this problem is solved when I use sudo truffle compile.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm doctor` to check your node environment health, this should fix the problem.

If it persists, consider downloading node.js using a version manager like nvm, then rerun `npm doctor`. this way you won't have to use `sudo truffle compile`.

Answer (score 0):

My env is MACOS. I meet the same problem, and I solve this by using "sudo truffle compile".This works. this problem comes out with my webstorm integrated terminal.But in the MACOS's self-terminal. It works without "sudo".You can try my way.

Comment: For trivial task like compiling a contract using sudo is in general a bad idea. The problem is likely a bad node o truffle installation. You could use a node installation manger like nvm to avoid using sudo unnecesarily.

Comment: Yes, I want to deploy my contract asap in order to continue my next step, so I use this way. I didn't solve the problem for several hours. I saw the same advice as yours from Github. I will try next time. Thanks~.